# Polyglot TeX, Monoglot PDF

Tags: compiling, languages

First, I do NOT want to write a document with multiple language in it. My goal is to have in a single TeX file in which I would write a section in say English and below the same section but translated in French. And when compiling, I could choose in which language to generate the PDF output.

Here is how I imagined it could have been implemented:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{englishSection}
    Hello world!
\end{englishSection}

\begin{frenchSection}
    Bonjour le monde!
\end{frenchSection}

\end{document}
```

Which could generate either an output showing:

> Hello world!

or another output showing:

> Bonjour tout le monde!

This problem seems too obvious for me to not have a solution, but I could not find any. I would totally be fine with a solution as basic as having a variable in a file that is used to determine which part to compile. Or should I use complete other methodology? As my document will be mostly figures and very little text, I think it could be easier to keep formatting coherent by having both languages next to each other.

Comment: You could create something based on the [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment) package.

Comment: My suggestion (as long as only two languages are involved) is to use`xifthen` and to do switching with `\ifthenelse{isEnglish}{Hello}{Bonjour}`.

Comment: `\newif\ifusingfrench\usingfrenchfalse` or `\usingfrenchtrue`. Then `\ifusingfrench <French> \else <English>\fi` and add `british` or `american` or `french` or whatever to the class call and load `babel`.

Comment: Or you may consider the `multiaudience` package which is pretty flexible.

Comment: @TeXnician Exactly what I wanted! I converted your comment into an answer. Also, do you know how to define the macro in texify parameters? I uses TeXworks and want to have one Typeset for each languages. I saw this line in the documentation: `pdflatex -jobnane file-execs "\def\CurrentAudience{execs}\input{file}"` but I couldn't make it work with texify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [TeXnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)'s comment, I could do what I wanted. Here is an example how to use `multiaudience` package to have multiple languages in same files:

```
\def\CurrentAudience{english}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multiaudience}

\SetNewAudience{french}
\SetNewAudience{english}

\begin{document}    
Common text for all languages

\begin{shownto}{french}
Bonjour tout le monde!
\end{shownto}

\begin{shownto}{english}
Hello world!
\end{shownto}

\end{document}
```

Where changing the first line to `\def\CurrentAudience{french}` set the compilation for French part.